# What is workaround to deploy webpartpages using sandbox solution in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sandbox-solution

Sharepoint sandbox solution does not support `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart` class.

Reference : 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/979636?OSMCSignIn=true&wa=wsignin1.0

So is there any other workaround excluding asp.net web part pages?

Answer (score 1):

One implication of this system is that a Web Part that is deployed in a sandboxed solution can be neither a provider nor a consumer Web Part in a Web Part connection. This is because each sandboxed Web Part renders entirely in a separate page object of its own. (Cross-page Web Part connections are possible with Web Parts that derive from the `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart` class, but that class is blocked by the shim `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`—see earlier in this topic.

Only Web Parts derived from the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart` class are supported in sandboxed solutions, and they do not allow cross-page Web Part connections.)

But you can think about the visual web part: [HOW TO: Create a Sandbox Compatible Visual Web Part with the Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Power Tools](http://toddbaginski.com/blog/create-a-sandbox-compatible-visual-web-part-with-the-visual-studio-2010-sharepoint-power-tools/#sthash.DIs0jVwh.dpuf)